# How to read collections seperately from firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote some code to read the collections and write to the logcat but I want to read them separately and add to a string to use them after. I have attributes as name, cityLONG, cityLAT, campaignStartDate, campaignEndDate under collections.

```
Logcat : 8sAtwKcm273R1io1Blre => {name=TEST_LOC, cityLONG=29.3054092, cityLAT=40.9301514, campaignStartDate=2019-04-30, campaignEndDate=2019-10-30}

public void readFirestore() {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("campaigns")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

[image: name, cityLONG, cityLAT, campaignStartDate, campaignEndDate]

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data that you want to get.

Comment: Sir I added all.

Comment: What is the exact data that you want to get?

Comment: I added the screenshot, I want to get "name, cityLONG, cityLAT, campaignStartDate, campaignEndDate" all of it seperately.

Comment: Have  you tried jackz314's answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getString()` on a document to get specific string fields, or use `get()` for other types and cast them yourself.

Your code would be like:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection("campaigns")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                String cityLONG = document.getString("cityLONG");
                                //and so on
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Glad I could help